# PHP: Price range / average calculation based on historical data

Tags: php, average, median

I'm building a little app that analyze ebay historical prices of sold items
and for some keywords/items the range is very wide because the search is too broad or simply wrong, infected by item not properly related

eg.

> search prices for iphone the results include either the phone, but
>   also the charger and accessories/unrelated items which adulterate the prices data...
>   so i have a range that goes form $5 fro a charger and 500$ for an
>   iphone

so, given that I will try to improve the search on my side, i'm wondering if there is math calculation to exclude the outliers

say I have

```
$1200
$549
$399
$519
$9
$599
$549
$9
$499 
$399
$519
$99
$5
$5
```

how to i get the price range to be $300-$600 instead of $10-$800 or so...

her ebelow the current php im using...not sure if is the best

```
    function remove_outliers($dataset, $magnitude = 1)
{
    $count     = count($dataset);
    $mean      = array_sum($dataset) / $count;                                                                                             // Calculate the mean
    $deviation = sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $dataset, array_fill(0, $count, $mean))) / $count) * $magnitude;                    // Calculate standard deviation and times by magnitude
    return array_filter($dataset, function ($x) use ($mean, $deviation) {return ($x <= $mean + $deviation && $x >= $mean - $deviation);}); // Return filtered array of values that lie within $mean +- $deviation.
}

function sd_square($x, $mean)
{
    return pow($x - $mean, 2);
}

function calculate_median($arr)
{
    sort($arr);
    $count     = count($arr);             
    $middleval = floor(($count - 1) / 2);  
    if ($count % 2) { 
        $median = $arr[$middleval];
    } else { 
        $low    = $arr[$middleval];
        $high   = $arr[$middleval + 1];
        $median = (($low + $high) / 2);
    }
    return $median;
}

 $prices = remove_outliers($prices); //$prices is the array with all the prices stored
 $trend  = calculate_median($prices);
$trend  = round(($trend));
$min    = round(min($prices));
$max    = round(max($prices));
```

Comment: You cannot be certain that the majority of items lies within the reasonable range. That is why your computation delivers a result, but you have absolutely no way of telling if that result makes any sense. You _cannot_ make such calculations without knowing the estimated range in advance.

Comment: what about comparing the range with the current price of a new item that i know for sure si the price of a specific item? can that be used as a center point?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but only if you know that this price is actually within the expected range. This only shifts the question to whether you have a reliable primary source or not.

Comment: what about instead to detect/exclude when the range is too broad (from $1 to $1000), or the range has too many values instead of few on the same range? i'm not a mathematician so i'm just guessing...

Comment: Trying to filter something without knowing the topology of the data points is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I find this function useful. The `$cleaness` variable will give granularity

```
/**
* Returns an average value from a dirt list of numbers.
*
* @require
* 
* $numbers  = an array of numbers
* $cleaness = a percentage value
* 
* @return integer
*   an average value from a cleaner list.
*/  

public function CleanAverage ( $numbers, $cleaness )  {

  
  // A 
  $extremes_to_remove = floor(count($numbers)/100*$cleaness);
  if ($extremes_to_remove < 2) {$extremes_to_remove = 2;}
        
  
  // B 
  sort ($numbers)         ; 
  
  
  // C
  //remove $extremes from top
  for ($i = 0; $i < ($extremes_to_remove/2); $i++)  {
    array_pop($numbers);
  }
  
  
  // D
  // revers order
  rsort($numbers);      
  
  
  // E
  //remove $extremes from top
  for ( $i = 0; $i < ($extremes_to_remove/2); $i++ ) {
    array_pop($numbers);
  }
  
  
  // F
  // average
  $average = array_sum($numbers)/count($numbers);
  return $average;

 }
```